# Why does my PyQt application open in the background on Mac OS X?

Tags: python, pyqt

I've got a PyQt app which I'm developing in Mac OS X, and whenever I try launching the app, it always is the very bottom application on the stack.  So after launching, I always need to command+tab all the way to the end of the application list to switch focus to it.

I read that this behavior can be fixed by launching the app with the "pythonw" command, but this doesn't make any difference, nor does renaming my script to have the .pyw extension (or doing both).  What could be causing this problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Based on this article http://diotavelli.net/PyQtWiki/PyInstallerOnMacOSX, you need to call app.raise_() after app.show()

```
ui = MainWindow()
ui.show()
ui.raise_()
```

ref: http://www.mail-archive.com/pyqt@riverbankcomputing.com/msg18945.html