# Qt: MainWindow does not appear until application is activated manually

Tags: qt, pyqt, py2app

In my (Py)Qt4 application, the main window doesn't appear until the user uses command-tab to switch away from the app and then command-tabs back to it.

The strange thing is that this problem **only shows itself when launched by double-clicking** my .app in the Finder.  If I launch the app **from the command line, it works correctly**.

Also, I've tried adding the following lines to my code, but nothing seems to do the trick:

```
mainWindow.show()
mainWindow.raise_()
mainWindow.repaint()
QApplication.postEvent(QEvent.ApplicationDeactivate)
QApplication.postEvent(QEvent.ApplicationActivate)
QApplication.instance().processEvents()
```

I thought that maybe this was somehow a thread-related issue, but I can insert this line pretty much anywhere:

```
assert threading.current_thread().name == "MainThread"
```

One final issue: I don't know if it's related, but my splash screen doesn't hide itself correctly (despite calling `splashscreen.finish(mainWindow)`).  (If I comment out the splash screen entirely, the main window still misbehaves as described above.)

Why does my application bundle behave differently than launching from the command-line?  Any idea how I can diagnose this?  I use `py2app` to generate my application bundle.

**Edit:** This mailing list item [explains](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/pythonmac-sig/2013-August/023992.html) the problem, gives a minimal test case.  SPOILER: It turns out the `argv_emulation` option is the problem.  It's not supposed to be used with GUI apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here turned out to be that I was using the `argv_emulation` option, which isn't intended for use with GUI apps.  Setting that option to `False` fixes the problem.

(See also: http://mail.python.org/pipermail/pythonmac-sig/2013-August/023992.html)

(Also, see the comments in [py2app/bootstrap/argv_emulation.py](https://bitbucket.org/ronaldoussoren/py2app/src/3e50b18722c57735988e13cfaacd59b163fda654/py2app/bootstrap/argv_emulation.py?at=default)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to solve this by calling show() followed by raise_() on your main window.

IIRC, you need both, and you may need them in that order. This works for the ubuntuone control panel app, which is PyQt and packaged using py2app.

There's more background info on the answer to this duplicate question : [Why does my PyQt application open in the background on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662559/why-does-my-pyqt-application-open-in-the-background-on-mac-os-x)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I am already calling show() and raise_() (in that order -- just updated my posting to reflect that, thanks).  I had seen the SO answer you just linked to, and I don't think I'm having the exact same issue.  The key here is that my app behaves *correctly* when launched from the command line, but misbehaves when launched from the app bundle.  I'm totally puzzled.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue; I found that the bug didn't manifest on a 32-bit Snow Leopard system, but the exact same py2app bundle exhibited the problem on 64-bit Lion and Mountain Lion.

Turning off `argv_emulation` didn't fix the problem for me (my application failed to launch in other ways instead).

My quick-and-dirty fix: after calling `show()`, add a call like:

```
os.system("open -a /path/to/your.app")
```

On OS X, this is basically equivalent to activating the (already running) app via its dock icon; the main window appears immediately.